# TypeScript default import vs non-default?

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, default

I'm having a hard time understanding the `default` keyword in TypeScript. So according to the [TypeScript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) the `default` keyword can be placed on classes, functions, and variables. I though don't understand what the advantage with or without the `default` keyword is, when it i.e. comes to classes. When I import a non-default class, I might do something like this:

```
import { MyStuff } from './myStuff';
```

When I import a default class, I might do that:

```
import MyStuff from './myStuff';
```

But then, after the import, I make no difference between both import types, when using the imported class:

```
class MyClass {
  private myStuff: MyStuff[] = [];
}
```

Could someone please explain the use of the `default` keyword using a little code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference between default and named *imports* except `import` syntax.

There's a difference between default and named *exports*. Named exports [follow strict syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Syntax) and export variables, functions or classes. Default exports accept [expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_the_default_export).

Comment: I'll just add that if you want to import ilke `export default` does but the module doesn't have export default in Typescript strict mode, you'll have to provide Typescript with the `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` compiler option